# Customized Reports for Protractor test

Tags: selenium, protractor

I am newbie from Selenium to Protractor. I am extensively using well customized reports such as Extent and ATU reports.

But in protractor i don't find anything apart from basic XML and jasmine2HTML. Is there anyone aware of any third party such as Extent/ATU in selenium for protractor?

Comment: What test library are you using?

Comment: it has a default json way of showing results.Maybe you can use that json file to send reports to that plugins and use

Comment: I am using Protractor and jasmine2HTML reporter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jasmine as your Protractor driver then you can create a custom reporter that does whatever you want.

https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html

Comment: Thx for your thoughts. Is it possible to customize the HTLM too using the above. I request you to help me with a elaborated example. Lets say, i need to add a test step line"Login Successfull" if the test has been passed successfully.